# Galaxy S6 Active always asking to sign in to WIFI

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I have an S6 active running 6.0.1 that just started prompting me to sign into my work WIFI after the update from 6.0 to 6.0.1. I have used this phone for over a year on the same network and the password is saved. When I click on the notification from the home screen it automatically signs me in to WIFI until the notification pops up again asking the same thing. None of our tech guys have been any help. I've changed to another network with the same exact results (home and work). Anyone have a clue how to get this to quit and stay signed in? It's driving me nuts!

Comment: Could you check and note the IP address assigned to your phone before and after the Sign in notification comes on? Settings>about phone>status I believe this would be caused by your router both work and home assigning a different ip address frequently to your phone. I'd like to confirm this.

Comment: There are two different IP addresses being assigned between home and work and has been that way since I got the phone. It's just odd that it started doing this shortly within a week after my last android update from AT&T.